# xsl adds empty space?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, rdf

I have a *sparql-results* XML file. I get it from *RD4J-Rest* API. When I open the file in *Notepad++*, it is as expected: (Sample)

```
<result>
        <binding name='ilAbk'>
            <literal>[A_2mim]Ll</literal>
        </binding>
</result>
```

Now I am using an XSL template to format the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:res="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template name="vb-result">
  <table id="main">
    <xsl:for-each select="res:results/res:result">
      <tr id="{generate-id()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="res:result">
  <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="/res:sparql/res:head/res:variable">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$current/res:binding[@name=$name]"/>
    </td>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="res:sparql">
  <xsl:call-template name="vb-result" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the final Table the `[A_2mim]Ll` has the same characters count (9). But when I access it with JavaScript and display it in the console, it get's ten additional empty characters. Here is the JavaScript part:

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("main");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = 
        function(row) 
        {
            return function() { 
                var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                var text = cell.innerHTML;
                var rid = row.getAttribute("id");
                console.log(text.length);
            };
        };

    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
```

Because I would like to use this name for the next query, I need to get rid of these characters. I know that I could cut it, but I was wondering if somebody would have an idea where these characters come from. It looks strange in the console - that's why I checked it with the `.length`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `<tr></tr>` is 9 chars, do you want `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`?

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in the Question. I get ten additional empty spaces. But i tried your input. I changed _cell.innerHTML_ to _cell.textContent_ but i still have the 19 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of this line here where you select the `binding` element

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$current/res:binding[@name=$name]"/>
```

The issue is you do not have a template matching `res:binding` or any of its descendants. This means XSLT will use its built-in templates, which ultimately select all descendent text nodes. This include the whitespace nodes, before and after the `literal` element that is used for indentation. It is this whitespace that is probably given you your confusing results.

There are a number of ways to solve it. Firstly, you can add a `xsl:strip-space` command after the `xsl:output` command, to tell XSLT to ignore whitespace only nodes

```
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Alternatively, you can be more specific with you `xsl:apply-templates` and target the `literal` element directly.

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="$current/res:binding[@name=$name]/res:literal"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim C both examples for solve work very nice. And also thank you for explaning.